# Get best parameters for time series without losing data

Tags: python, deep-learning, time-series, hyperparameters, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm trying to do demand sensing for a dataset. Presently I have 157 weeks of data(~3years) and I have to predict next month(8 weeks).In the training dataset, I'm using 149weeks as a train and the last 8 weeks as Val to get the best hyperparameters. But I have observed that in the pred result, there's a huge gap in wmapes between Val and pred. I'm not sure if im overfitting because Val wmape is good.

the aim is to get best parameters such that the result pred will good for last month(last 4 weeks/8weeks).

note: there is a gap in train and pred i.e. if the train is till 31st jan22, pred will start from 1st mar22.

How can I overcome this problem?
Details: dataset: timeseries , algo: TCNmodel(darts lib),lang:python.

Answer (score 0):

How you should split the data depends on some factors:

If you have a seasonal influence over a year, you can take a complete year for validation and two years for training.

If your data can be predicted from the last n-weeks, you can take some random n-week splits from the full dataset.

Whats more important here is that I think there's an error in your training pipeline. You should have a sliding window over n-weeks over the full training data and always predict the next 8 weeks from every n-week sequence.

Comment: so darts uses sliding window format for tcn. And Even if i do a sliding window val,wont the best hyperparameters be which are for overfitted model. My dataset comes under lumpy forecastability,so theres no seasonality or trend. And since the only way to find the proper parameters is remove somedata from train and val and treat it as unknown,get best parameters, then club both train and val and train a model on those hyperparameters.But in this scenario ,I feel due to gap in pred and parameters obtained(train without val),i think the arameters obtained are not apt for pred.

Comment: What is your actual prediction error? What do you exactly mean by hyperparameters? What is your data, is it even possible to forecast? Please share some more information..

Comment: The data is confidential(ofc). few details about the data: it is weekly sales data, and it comes under the lumpy category(https://frepple.com/blog/demand-classification/). Im using wmape as error.
Regarding hyperparameters, im using TCN model from darts lib,so the hyperparameters im using are input_chunk_length,Learning_rate and number of epochs.
The scenario is I have to predict the sales of coming months. Now I have data till Mar,so i assumed i have data till jan as train and feb as val and got best hyperparameters,to check if is it possible to get forecast the data and i got ~0.35wmape.

Comment: But in reality the val we are speaking abt is unknown,so i have to use train and split the last month and treat is as val.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to find out, whether your model is already good or not. Is 0.35 wmape good? How do you know that a lower wmape is possible?

Comment: 0.35 wmape is very good in our industry, our regular wmape is ~0.45-0.5